# Do I automatically start baking if I have 10,000 or more tezos in my wallet?

Tags: baking, vps, ubuntu

I am just wondering if I can run the wallet with my private key on an cheap Ubuntu VPS to start earning baking rewards.

Answer (score 6):

No you have to explicitly register as a baker and run the baking and endorsing processes on your node.

Comment: Awesome, I am running bakechain on my local computer, and when I deposited the 10,000 tezies the status changed to "baking".  On the tezos explorer it says I am delegated to my own address.  Does that mean I'm registered and I have to wait 20 days or so to start baking?

Comment: I'm not familiar with bakechain so you should probably wait for someone more familiar to comment but it sounds like that is the case from what you say